# How can I implement CBC-MAC with DES?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, des, cbc-mac

I should implement a MAC-CBC generation method in C# with some information about the cryptography algorithm. Here's what I have:

- I should use DES.
- The key is `byte[] {11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11}`
- The data (16 bytes) should be encrypted in 8-byte parts. First 8 bytes is encrypted using `Instance Vector = new byte[8]` (8 bytes with 0 value). (CBC?)
- that last 8 bytes of the encrypted value should be converted to Hex string. this is the result I should send.

With this information, I have implemented the following method:

```
public static string Encrypt(byte[] data)
{
    var IV = new byte[8];
    var key = new byte[] { 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11 };
    var result = new byte[16];

    // Create DES and encrypt.
    var des = DES.Create();
    des.Key = key;
    des.IV = IV;
    des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
    des.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV);
    cryptoTransform.TransformBlock(data, 0, 16, result, 0);

    // Get the last eight bytes of the encrypted data.
    var lastEightBytes = new byte[8];
    Array.Copy(result, 8, lastEightBytes, 0, 8);

    // Convert to hex.
    var hexResult = string.Empty;
    foreach (byte ascii in lastEightBytes)
    {
        int n = (int)ascii;
        hexResult += n.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0');
    }

    return hexResult;
}
```

The sample raw data they have provided me is: `input=byte[] {0, 6, 4, 1, 6, 4, 1, 7, E, E, F, F, F, F, B, B)` which should return the output of value: `A7CBFB3C730B059C`. This means the last eight bytes of encrypted data should be: `byte[] {167, 203, 251, 60, 115, 11, 05, 156}`.

But unfortunately using the above method, I get: `32D91200D0007632`. meaning my encrypted data is not correct. (the last eight byte of my method's generated encrypted value is `byte[] {50, 207, 18, 0, 208, 0, 118, 50}`).

Is there any way that I can find out what I should do to get to A7CB...? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: CBC-MAC is not secure for messages that have padding applied to them. That means a message must be the size of DES's block or you've lost a fair amount of security. You should use a CMAC or HMAC instaed. CMAC is a CBC-MAC done right. And DES was deprecated years ago because its insecure. You should probably switch to a modern block cipher, like 3-key Triple DES, AES or Cameilla.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CBC-MAC requires a zero Initialisation Vector.  Much better to specify the IV explicitly:

```
var IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

You say your key is `byte[] { 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11 }` are those bytes in hex or in base 10?  You might want to try:

```
var key = new byte[] { 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11 };
```

and see if that works better.

Comment: Thanks. Although I could not get the correct result. But this was one way I hadn't tried.

Comment: @Kaymar: looking again at the question, are you treating the plaintext, `{ 0, 6, 4, 1, 6, 4, 1, 7, E, E, F, F, F, F, B, B }` as hex or decimal?  Are you sure that this is the correct plaintext, with all values below 16?

Comment: This bytearray is calculated by XORing PAN number with PIN code by using a custom algorithm. this bytearray is what the bank has provided me. I'm sure the `{0, 6, 4, 1, ...}` is the correct array. and have used `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` to get the byte array of string: "06416417EEFFFFBB`. Do you suggest I should conert them to byte array using another approach?

Comment: Your string looks to me like hex.  You should try it as 8 hex bytes, not as 16 ASCII bytes/nibbles.

Answer (score 2):

The [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) project has a generic MAC-CBC implementation that should work on any **SymmetricAlgorithm** - even if it's used, internally, only to implement **MACTripleDES**.

You can find the MIT.X11 licensed source code [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/Mono.Security.Cryptography/MACAlgorithm.cs). Use it *as-is* or compare it to your own code.