# GCM or CCM implementation of C#

Tags: c#, cryptography

Can any one point me to any live implementation of CBC-MAC Mode (CCM)or Galois/Counter Mode (GCM) in C#?
It seems that Microsoft has not created any implementation similar to AesCryptoServiceProvider. Am I right?

I did went through: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2009/03/17/authenticated-symmetric-encryption-in-net/, bit it's more of a "would look something like" rather than actual implementation.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement CBC-MAC with DES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631998/how-can-i-implement-cbc-mac-with-des)

Comment: That is not a correct duplicate.  The OP just mis-named "Counter with CBC-MAC (CCM)" mode.

Comment: No, there's nothing inbox for it.  It's on the TODO list, though https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7023.

Comment: correct,so that means it's still not yet implemented!

Answer (score 2):

By the way, while there wasn't an official MS implementation at the time of this question, there is one now:

AES-GCM: [AesGcm Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=net-5.0) (System.Security.Cryptography)

AES-CCM: [AesCcm Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesccm?view=net-5.0) (System.Security.Cryptography)

Both are supported from:

- .Net: 5.0
- .Net Core: 3.0
- .Net Standard 2.1